# IE7 and IE8 float left does not work

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, width

I have the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VyXWp/1/

```
#wizard li {
    display: inline;
    min-width:100px;
    float:left;
}
```

The second divs width should be calculated based on the text width.

In IE7 and IE8 it is messed up.

For some reason the 'a' element gets the width of the span2 div instead of the text.

---

***Edit:***

After more digging i noticed that the problem was not width but float. If i set no width, the float doesn't work. It doesn't limit the width to that of the text.

---

***Edit 2:***

Couldn't find any pure css solution that worked and kept the width auto, so in the end i calculate the width with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find any pure css solution that worked and kept the width auto, so in the end i calculate the width with javascript for old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The **CSS** width property takes a fixed parameter when passing precise values, but in terms of percentage, if you set the width of an element to 50% or 100% it will take the percentage of the width its parent element is.

so if you have a `div` with a width of 500px and `p` tag inside with a width at 50% the `p` tag would be 250px, vice versa with a 100%.

i short my suggestion is to make sure that the parent element either has a fixed width or percentage

you might also find this helpful
http://learnlayout.com/percent.html

Comment: Thank you for the replay, i knew how the percent value gets calculated. And since the parent is a block element it takes the width of the content, so it should have worked. Please take a look at the edit question.

Comment: i can't understand what it is that your trying to do exactly. please elaborate so i can better assist you.